# Non nullable type guarding in custom RxJS filter operator

Tags: typescript, rxjs

How can I achieve non nullable type guarding in my custom RxJS operator? Next code

```js
export const filterNil = <T>() => (source: Observable<T | undefined | null>): Observable<T> => source.pipe(
    filter<T>((value: T): value is NonNullable<T> => value !== null && value !== undefined),
);
```

throws ts error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<T | null | undefined, T>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<T | null | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'.
      Type 'T | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a problem using next code:

```
export const filterNil = <T>() => (source: Observable<T>): Observable<NonNullable<T>> => source.pipe(
    filter<T, NonNullable<T>>((value: T): value is NonNullable<T> => value !== null && value !== undefined),
);
```

Comment: In cases like this I like using `source.pipe(switchMap(value => value !== undefined ? of(value) : EMPTY))`, which takes care of types without needing a custom operator.

Comment: Or possibly to use `filter(Boolean)` as described here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5163

Comment: @Felix No, you can not use Boolean since it will treat `0, '', false` as false.